# Products are showing up under magento subcategories but not on categories - system

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I'm having an issue as I have to organise some products to display on the top of the pages on the website. 
It works on the subcategories and I change the position, everything fine. But when I go to the main category (389 products) for example, it doesn't shows up any products. When on the website, it shows up all the products (389).  In some other categories it shows some products on magento, but not all the ones that are showing up on the website. 
Does anyone knows what can be happening and how I can make the products appear under the category on magento to change the positions? 
I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Magento. Plz check whether you assigned the products to that category or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your category is set to an anchor category and therefore that number is listing all the products that are available under the child categories.

Turn off anchor category and you will see it goes to 0.

If you have flat tables enabled for categories and products, be sure that you have re-indexed.

Clear your cache.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, it is magento defaul function.

You can see **Is Anchor** option in **Desing Setting**.

In magento category, any category set **In Anchor** as "**Yes**" it will show all products which is assign in **current category** and it's **child category.**

Same works on frontend side, when you go any category which is set **Is Anchor** as **Yes** it will show **all the product** of **current category** and it's **child category.**

If you don't need, you have to set category **Is Anchor** as "**No**".

You can understand diffrece between by set it **Is Anchor** as **Yes** or **No**.